# Jquery look for all instances of a class on button press, and remove an additional class from them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry if the title is confusing, I'm very new to Javascript & Jquery so it's hard to find the right way to ask a question sometimes.

Here's the situation:

I've got a lot of divs all with a class of thumbnail:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
```

Additionally, some of those classes may be expanded at any given time, like so:

```
<div class="thumnail expanded">
```

This all works great and they expand as needed.

I'd like to add some logic that fires on click, when a user clicks any of these thumbnails to expand it:

```
$( ".thumbnail a" ).click(function() {
});
```

This check works fine, and I can fire a popup on click that registers the thumbnail anchor clicks like a charm.

What I don't know is how to check for any instances of thumbnail which also have a class of expanded, and remove that class. I tried something like:

```
$( ".thumbnail .expanded").removeClass("expanded");
```

Within the thumbnail click check, but to no avail. Not quite sure what I'm missing here, so help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take out the space between the two classes, like so:

```
$( ".thumbnail.expanded").removeClass("expanded");
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use * or ~ selector: `$("div.thumbnail[class~='expanded']").removeClass("expanded");`

Answer (score 1):

MHardwicks' answer is great & works. I've upvoted it.

So you know, The reason this works:

```
$( ".thumbnail.expanded").removeClass("expanded");
```

and

```
$( ".thumbnail .expanded").removeClass("expanded");
```

does not work, is that the space means "Class within the other class." So if you had

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="expanded">Yay, I'm expanded</div>
</div>
```

Then your code with the space would remove the expanded, which is inside of thumbnail. However, since the classes are on the same element, you must put them together, e.g. `.thumbnail.expanded`, so you can target it.

If you want to know more about CSS Selectors, you can do this great little interactive tutorial [CSS Diner](http://flukeout.github.io/)

Comment: This is a very helpful explanation for the 'why' of it. Much appreciated!